# Save values after redirect

Tags: php

I am saving values into `$_SESSiON` variable, but after I submit form, which redirect me to the same page, `$_SESSION` variable is empty.

```
include 'googleauthorize.php';
include 'googleTransfer.php';


if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
    unset($_SESSION['auth']);


if(isset($_REQUEST['auth'])){
    //Initialize google client
    $_SESSION['auth'] = new GoogleAuthorize(__DIR__ . '/../oauth-credentials.json', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?auth", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
    //Get authorize URL
    $authUrl = $_SESSION['auth']->obtainAuthorizeUrl();

    //Redirect  
    if(!isset($_GET['code'])){
        $_SESSION['auth']->redirect($authUrl);
    }
    //Authentificate and return token
    $_SESSION['token'] = $_SESSION['auth']->obtainAccessToken();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['refreshToken']))
    {
        $_SESSION['refreshToken'] = $_SESSION['auth']->getRefreshToken();
        //Call method to save token into DB
    }
}elseif(isset($_REQUEST['upload'])){
    if(isset($_SESSION['auth']))
    {
        //Initialize google client
        $_SESSION['auth'] = new GoogleAuthorize(__DIR__ . '/../oauth-credentials.json', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
    }
//Here is undefined index 'token'
    $_SESSION['auth']->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);

    //Initialize new object for file transfer
    new googleTransfer($_SESSION['auth']->getGoogleClient());
    }
```

This is content of `$_SESSION` variable in `elseif` statement. Which makes me confused because there is only `auth` saved inside, which doesn't have anything set inside.

```
    Array
(
    [auth] => GoogleAuthorize Object
        (
            [client:GoogleAuthorize:private] => Google_Client Object
                (
                    [auth:Google_Client:private] => Google\Auth\OAuth2 Object
                        (
                            [authorizationUri:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri Object
                                (
                                    [scheme:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => https
                                    [userInfo:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => 
                                    [host:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => accounts.google.com
                                    [port:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => 
                                    [path:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => /o/oauth2/auth
                                    [query:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => 
                                    [fragment:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => 
                                )

                            [tokenCredentialUri:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri Object
                                (
                                    [scheme:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => https
                                    [userInfo:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => 
                                    [host:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => www.googleapis.com
                                    [port:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => 
                                    [path:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => /oauth2/v4/token
                                    [query:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => 
                                    [fragment:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => 
                                )

                            [redirectUri:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => http://localhost:81/FileTransfer/src/testik.php?auth
                            [clientId:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 108715515230-g8e7tjh2d7luiggtfes6fsdv17n794hu.apps.googleusercontent.com
                            [clientSecret:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => Ab-DiaYYRnVSFf8JGay-TIMN
                            [username:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [password:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [scope:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [state:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [code:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [issuer:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 108715515230-g8e7tjh2d7luiggtfes6fsdv17n794hu.apps.googleusercontent.com
                            [audience:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [sub:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [expiry:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 3600
                            [signingKey:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [signingAlgorithm:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [refreshToken:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [accessToken:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [idToken:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [expiresIn:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [expiresAt:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [issuedAt:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [grantType:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => 
                            [extensionParams:Google\Auth\OAuth2:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [http:Google_Client:private] => 
                    [cache:Google_Client:private] => 
                    [token:Google_Client:private] => 
                    [config:Google_Client:private] => Array
                        (
                            [application_name] => 
                            [base_path] => https://www.googleapis.com
                            [client_id] => 108715515230-g8e7tjh2d7luiggtfes6fsdv17n794hu.apps.googleusercontent.com
                            [client_secret] => Ab-DiaYYRnVSFf8JGay-TIMN
                            [redirect_uri] => http://localhost:81/FileTransfer/src/testik.php?auth
                            [state] => 
                            [developer_key] => 
                            [use_application_default_credentials] => 
                            [signing_key] => 
                            [signing_algorithm] => 
                            [subject] => 
                            [hd] => 
                            [prompt] => 
                            [openid.realm] => 
                            [include_granted_scopes] => 
                            [login_hint] => 
                            [request_visible_actions] => 
                            [access_type] => offline
                            [approval_prompt] => auto
                            [retry] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [cache_config] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [token_callback] => 
                        )

                    [logger:Google_Client:private] => 
                    [deferExecution:Google_Client:private] => 
                    [requestedScopes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
                        )

                )

            [authUrl:GoogleAuthorize:private] => 

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=108715515230-g8e7tjh2d7luiggtfes6fsdv17n794hu.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A81%2FFileTransfer%2Fsrc%2Ftestik.php%3Fauth&state&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&approval_prompt=auto
                [token:GoogleAuthorize:private] => 
            )

)
```

Comment: session_start() should always be called so try to remove the if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)

Comment: That didn't help, I still get undefined index.

Comment: undefined index for which variable?

Comment: for variable `$_SESSION['token']` which I am trying to access in `elseif` block

Comment: EDITED : You set `$_SESSION['token']` in the if statement but what happens if you go to the `elseif` block?

Comment: There I get undefined index. `$_SESSION` has global scope so it doesn't matter if I save some value inside `if` statement of outside or no ?

Comment: It is global scope indeed. The problem here is that if code goes to elseif statament you create `$_SESSION['auth']` but not `$_SESSION['token']`

Comment: If it`s global then it should have been created and saved when I first created it in `if` statement.

Comment: What happens if it never went to the if statement but instead it went to the else if? Have you tried what i wrote as an answer?

Comment: This is just script that I want to use for testing my two classes for authentication and file upload. So I am just executing these two blocks with `?auth` and `?upload` requests. So it will throw undefined index, but It doesn't matter because I always run `auth` block first

Comment: Try to print_r() in the else statement all the variables just to be sure that they are not null or something else. With the way that you mentioned it should work though.

Answer (score 2):

```
include 'googleauthorize.php';
include 'googleTransfer.php';


if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
    unset($_SESSION['auth']);


if(isset($_REQUEST['auth']) || isset($_REQUEST['upload'])){

    if(!isset($_SESSION['auth']){

    $_SESSION['auth'] = new GoogleAuthorize(__DIR__ . '/../oauth-credentials.json', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?auth", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
    //Get authorize URL
    $authUrl = $_SESSION['auth']->obtainAuthorizeUrl();

    //Redirect  
    if(!isset($_GET['code'])){
        $_SESSION['auth']->redirect($authUrl);
    }
    //Authentificate and return token
    $_SESSION['token'] = $_SESSION['auth']->obtainAccessToken();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['refreshToken']))
    {
        $_SESSION['refreshToken'] = $_SESSION['auth']->getRefreshToken();
        //Call method to save token into DB
    }
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['upload'])){

    new googleTransfer($_SESSION['auth']->getGoogleClient());

    }
}
```

Comment: Yea that would work, but I also need to use `redirect` and almost everything that is in first `if` statement. Basically I will be authenticating again, which I don't want, because I am already, I just somehow need to get `token` which I wanted to save into `$_SEASSON['token']` to `elseif` block

Comment: Then try not to have and if/else. Put an if statement which creates the auth and refreshes the token . After that put another if statement to check for upload. This way you will always create an auth and a token.

Comment: Don't I do that ? `elseif` is same as if I had second `if` statement.  Could you rearrange your code if I misunderstood you please ?

Comment: @jemcaj Edited answer. Could you try it please?

Comment: @jemcaj I don't know exactly how you need it, because i don't know what you completely trying to achieve. However, you should be sure that `auth` and `token` are set before trying to upload.

Comment: Still nothing. I also put initializing of `$_SESSION['auth']` inside `if(!isset($_GET['code']))` so it will initialize only once and not twice (after redirect) as before. But It does weird things. In `upload` block, there is still only `$_SESSION['auth']` but probably initialized after redirect because some variables are missing

Comment: @jemcaj 1. remove the `if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)` 2. Enable error logging 3. Show the errors here

Answer (score 2):

```
    include 'googleauthorize.php';
    include 'googleTransfer.php';


    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
        unset($_SESSION['auth']);


    if(isset($_REQUEST['auth'])){

    // You have initialize the session variable auth here.


        $_SESSION['auth'] = new GoogleAuthorize(__DIR__ . '/../oauth-credentials.json', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?auth", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
        //Get authorize URL
        $authUrl = $_SESSION['auth']->obtainAuthorizeUrl();

        //Redirect  
        if(!isset($_GET['code'])){
            $_SESSION['auth']->redirect($authUrl);
        }

        $_SESSION['token'] = $_SESSION['auth']->obtainAccessToken();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['refreshToken']))
        {
            $_SESSION['refreshToken'] = $_SESSION['auth']->getRefreshToken();
            //Call method to save token into DB
        }
    }elseif(isset($_REQUEST['upload'])){
         // but how will it set here? when not having value? You have put the //session initialize here also.

            $_SESSION['auth'] = new GoogleAuthorize(__DIR__ . '/../oauth-credentials.json', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");


     if(isset($_SESSION['auth']))
        {
        $_SESSION['auth']->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }
        //Initialize new object for file transfer
        new googleTransfer($_SESSION['auth']->getGoogleClient());       
}
```

Comment: Please consider writing a __proper__ answer, rather than just editing code and placing brief comments.

Comment: the code in the elseif is change. If you can see that with lil concentration.. :P

Comment: An answer worth its salt doesn't require a little concentration to understand it. It is clear and well explained. [This link might be helpful for you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: **Thanks Alots** :)